# How to determine if img's onerror occured because of no internet connection or wrong (/dead) url?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm aware of the onerror handler on images. What I want to know is why the error occurs. With onerror I get the same result whether I'm offline (I can't reach the server) or the image url is wrong, or dead (the server cannot return a valid image).

I can't seem to find out the returned HTTP status.

I would need this, because I want to place a placeholder image on broken images (labeled "you need to be online" but only if the user is offline). Ideally this would only trigger if the user is offline and the image cannot be retrieved from the cache either.

Is there any solution for this?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can test your access to a safe URL, like google.com, or your server. If you have access that means you have Internet. If you have access to this url and you can't load the image the link is probably broken.

Your need is somewhat cumbersome ^^. In any case link can be temporally broken, Internet connection can be on and off, and request can fail. There is no certainty.
On a error just put a placeholder, saying something like "You seem off line".
And then using load() on your web page, if there is an image not loaded, test your safe url, if you can reach it, replace your "you seem off line" by "link seems broken" or you can even try to load the image again. The ideal is clearly to avoid calling your safe url more than once to avoid unnecessary traffic.

Today the website rely more on their user to know if this is a broken link or broken connection. On some website i saw a button to signal a broken link.

Comment: Thanks, this could work but it seems a bit cumbersome mainly because I want to apply this as a general solution to (almost) all of my images, and that would be done easily if I could write all the code in the onerror handler.
A problem with this is that it may not be accurate all the time: if I can reach the safe url, then loose my net connection it will report as the image is broken which might be not the case..

Comment: thanks, well yes that could work. I forgot to mention, this in fact is not used on a traditional website, but rather on a webapp built with phonegap and used primarily on tablets. What we wanted to do was add a placeholder "you seem offline" on broken images, but I wanted to make sure I add this only if in fact the user is offline.